# IE10 displays bizarre behavior when rendering images?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

By directly, I mean when you type the URL into the address bar.  By bizarre, I mean it appears to be domain dependent.

In IE10, if I copy paste this

```
http://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/faviconr3.ico
```

into the address bar I get a broken image displayed.

However if I put that exact image on my own domain and point to it, everything works fine.

```
http://foo.com/favicons/plus.google.com.ico  // example
```

Why does it seem to display the image based on what domain it is on?

I have already cleared all the cache under options.

Comment: Did you check typos? Does it work in other browser? Sometheing like "," instead of "." or lower-case character instead of capital letter? (Can sometime happen...)

Comment: It works in other browsers, I've already spent time narrowing it down to an IE issue.  I think, but I'm not sure it has to do with PNGs encapsulated into ICOs, in IE only.

Comment: Check the mimetype of the image, from ssl.gstatic.com the image is type of `image/x-icon`. What is the type when you load the image from your own domain?

Comment: IE10 has something called an image report in the F12 tools, but even this did not appear to tell me the mime type, where can I find this info, to see if is causing the issue and what the work around is?

Comment: I'm not sure about IE10, I've only IE11 at hands. Though the mimetype should be the same in FF or Chrome too. In FF you can right-click the image, select "Image properties", and in "General" tab you can see the "Type".

Answer (score 2):

The `Content-Type` of the response is likely different in the two cases. This is the HTTP response header - *not* the `.ico` suffix on the URL, which has no effect.

Comment: IE10 has something called an image report in the F12 tools, but even this did not appear to tell me the mime type, where can I find this info, to see if is causing the issue and what the work around is?

Comment: @user3294399 In IE: (1) Press F12 to bring up Developer Tools (2) Open the "Network" tab (3) Click the "Start capturing" button (4) Enter your URL and press enter. Down bottom in the "Network" tab you will see your HTTP GET request, and the Type column will contain the returned `Content-Type`.

Comment: it is image/x-icon in both, so I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: oddly I can see the image displayed under detailed view -> content.  Don't know why IE won't display it the actual browser.

Answer (score 0):

IE will respects a FavIcon specified using a LINK REL="ICON" element *if a TYPE attribute is present with value "image/x-icon"*

[Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/02/11/ie9-release-candidate-minor-changes-list.aspx)